# Converting a matrix to an array

Tags: matlab

I want to get the highest coefficients after applying PCA to an image using Matlab. For this I'm going to convert the matrix of pixels to an array and then sort it. How to do it? or else is there a better way to sort the highest 10 PCA coefficients ?

The sample code is as follows.

```
close all
clear all

imIdx = 8;
cropCorner = [100 100];

resampleRatio = 1.25;

N = 2;   % window size
M = 64; % block size

im  = imread('kodim06.png');
[H,W,~] = size(im);

for k = 1:length(resampleRatio)   
  r = resampleRatio(k);   
  cropWidth = floor(M/r);

  img = double(im(cropCorner(1):cropCorner(1)+cropWidth-1, ...
                  cropCorner(2):cropCorner(2)+cropWidth-1));
  %img = imresize(img,[M M],'bilinear');    
  pmap = emresample(img,N,'verbose');                  
  fmap = fft2c(pmap);


  % display p-map
  figure;
  subplot(131)
  imshow(img,[])
  subplot(132)
  imshow(pmap,[])
  subplot(133)
  imshow(abs(rmcenter(fmap)),[]);

  filename = sprintf('F:/Project/ImgPro/EM/im%i_r%.2f.png',imIdx,(r-1)*100);

  imwrite(fmap,filename)
  %disp(fmap);

  coeff = pca(fmap);  

  eigval = eig(coeff);
  disp(eigval);

end
```

Comment: A matrix is an array... are you referring to a 1D array? Also. PCA returns a set of vectors, not pixels.

Comment: Yes, I want to convert into a 1D array.

Comment: Please show the code where you apply PCA to the image, so we can see where you're stuck. So far I don't see the problem you're having. Your question makes little sense.

Comment: I edited the question with the code. Here I want the highest 10 PCA coefficients, so that I can use them for a SVM.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation to `pca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html):

> Each column of `coeff` contains coefficients for one principal component, and the columns are in descending order of component variance.

So, after

```
coeff = pca(fmap);
```

you can simply keep the first 10 columns of `coeff` to get the 10 largest principal components:

```
coeff = coeff(:,1:10);
```

Comment: when I did that I got the error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". how to solve it ?.

Comment: That means you don’t have 10 dimensions in your data. If you don’t have 10 dimensions, you can’t get 10 principal components. What are you computing PCA on? I don’t have `emresample` or `fft2c`, so cannot are what you are seeing.